# Обработка касаний (струны в гитаре)

Tags: android, touch, multi-touch

Практикуюсь, решил сделать что-то типа гитары, но не придумаю, как правильно обрабатывать нажатия.

Есть 6 струн и надо, когда палец касается верхней струны и идет вниз (зацепляя остальные), чтобы к ним всем, по очереди, применялись анимации.

Смог сделать это только при одиночном касании, если по очереди нажимать на струны то все работает, если прислонить палец о водить по экрану то нет.

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.string1:
                str1.startAnimation(touch_string);
                return false;
            case R.id.string2:
                str2.startAnimation(touch_string);
                return false;
            case R.id.string3:
                str3.startAnimation(touch_string);
                return false;
            case R.id.string4:
                str4.startAnimation(touch_string);
                return false;
            case R.id.string5:
                str5.startAnimation(touch_string);
                return false;
            case R.id.string6:
                str6.startAnimation(touch_string);
                return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Игрался с различными экшенами MotionEvent, но ничего не получилось, как же это правильно реализовать?

Буду благодарен за ответ!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что в данном случае нужно отслеживать не `ACTION_DOWN`, а `ACTION_MOVE` . Определите нужную область, повесьте слушатель и обработайте как необходимо. К примеру, берете положение и при совпадении в определенных координатах/промежутке координат выполняйте действие

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                x = event.getRawX();
                y = event.getRawY();
                //TODO обработать нужные места 
                ...
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```